# PYQT5 Cannot display window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm a pyqt novice. I try to build a window. This is my code

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)

   w = QWidget()

   # 设置窗口标题
   w.setWindowTitle("第一个PyQt")

   # 展示窗口
   w.show()

   # 程序进行循环等待状态
   app.exec()
```

However, after running, no window is displayed and no related error is obtained. The console prints ：Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: runs fine for me. opens an empty window with the windowTitle you set

Comment: Please run your code in a terminal or prompt to see the full traceback, then [edit] your post and share it with us. I obviously assume that you *did* properly install PyQt5.

Comment: It seems that it's my Python problem. I reinstalled a higher version of Python to solve this problem. I don't understand the specific reason